# How to convert from unicode to ASCII

Tags: c#-3.0

Is there any way to convert unicode values to ASCII?

Answer (score 25):

To simply strip the accents from unicode characters you can use something like:

```
string.Concat(input.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Where(
  c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Not a conversion but a normalization of characters!

Answer (score 5):

Technically, yes you can by using `Encoding.ASCII`.

Example (from byte[] to ASCII):

```
// Convert Unicode to Bytes

byte[] uni = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Whatever unicode string you have");

// Convert to ASCII

string Ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(uni);
```

Just remember Unicode a much larger standard than Ascii and there will be characters that simply cannot be correctly encoded. [Have a look here](http://www.beginningtoseethelight.org/ascii/) for tables and a little more information on the two encodings.

Comment: This isn't going to work. This encodes the string as UTF-16 bytes, then *misinterprets* those bytes as if they were ASCII (which of course they are not). No conversion is done between character values by these methods.
Result: `"W␀h␀a␀t␀e␀v␀e␀r␀ ␀u␀n␀i␀c␀o␀d␀e␀ ␀s␀t␀r␀i␀n␀g␀ ␀y␀o␀u␀ ␀h␀a␀v␀e␀"` (using the ␀ [control picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures) for the [ASCII NUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)).

Comment: @Kyle_Rozendo Yes, I did. You still can't just take one encoding's bytes and read them as another encoding! That's what makes "W" → "W␀". If it doesn't work for a W, it's not a problem of character support (ASCII has a W). Try this approach the other direction (ASCII → UTF-16) and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I would argue that you can convert from Unicode to ASCII. That it doesn't make for a very readable output is an artifact of ASCII fundamentally not being able to represent unicode at a character-to-character level. This answer _does however_ convert Unicode to ASCII, in some way, which is what the OP asked for. (11 years later I know)

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you mean by "convert".

You can transliterate using the [AnyAscii](https://github.com/anyascii/anyascii#net) package.

```
// C#
using AnyAscii;

string s = "άνθρωποι".Transliterate();
// anthropoi
```

Answer (score 3):

You CAN'T convert from Unicode to ASCII. Almost every character in Unicode cannot be expressed in ASCII, and those that *can* be expressed have exactly the same codepoints in ASCII as in UTF-8, which is probably what you have. Almost the only thing you can do that is even close to the right thing is to discard all characters above codepoint 128, and even that is very likely nowhere near what your requirements say. (The other possibility is to simplify accented or umlauted letters to make more than 128 characters 'nearly' expressible, but that still doesn't even begin to actually cover Unicode.)

Answer (score 3):

This workaround might better suit your needs. It strips the unicode chars from a string and only keeps the ASCII chars.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("eéêëèiïaâäàåcç  test");
char[] chars = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytes);
string line = new String(chars);
line = line.Replace("?", "");
//Results in "eiac test"
```

Please note that the 2nd "space" in the character input string is the char with ASCII value 255

Comment: Unless that character happens to be a "?", of course, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Well, seeing as how there's some 100,000+ unicode characters and only 128 ASCII characters, a 1-1 mapping is obviously impossible.

You can use the `Encoding.ASCII` object to get the ASCII byte values from a Unicode string, though.

Answer (score 0):

If your metadata fields only accept ASCII input. Unicode characters can be converted to their TEX equivalent through MathJax. What is MathJax?
MathJax is a JavaScript display engine for rendering TEX or MathML-coded mathematics in browsers without requiring font installation or browser plug-ins. Any modern browser with JavaScript enabled will be MathJax-ready. For general information about MathJax, visit mathjax.org.