# Remove illegal characters from filename to burn on CD

Tags: c#

I have done research but my app downloads mp3 files every once in a while I get weird filename which doesn't hurt until I try to  burn them to CD. Below is a good example. 
***The Animals - House of the Rising Sun (1964) + clip compilation ♫♥ 50 YEARS - counting.mp3*** 
I have some code to try and catch illegal characters but it doesn't stop this filename. Is there a better way to catch the weird stuff the code I use currently is:

```
 public static string RemoveIllegalFileNameChars(string input, string replacement = "")
    {
        if (input.Contains("?"))
        {
            input = input.Replace('?', char.Parse(" "));
        }
        if (input.Contains("&"))
        {
            input = input.Replace('&', char.Parse("-"));
        }
        var regexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + 
                          new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
        var r = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(regexSearch)));

        return r.Replace(input, replacement);
    }
```

Comment: Since the name you've posted is completely valid you should figure out what CD burner tool is expecting and filter everything out. There is nothing wrong with your code (at first glance) but it looks like your burner software is pickier.

Comment: That filename contains only legal characters, as far as your filesystem is concerned, because otherwise it could not exist with that name.  So, `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` won't help you here.  Perhaps your CD burning software only supports ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks I am using the media burner from code project https://www.codeproject.com/articles/24544/burning-and-erasing-cd-dvd-blu-ray-media-with-c-an

Comment: By the way, are you burning these files as an audio disc or a data disc?  If the latter and this software passes through the original filename to the CD's filesystem, then you're at the mercy of whatever characters and filename lengths _that_ filesystem supports.

Comment: Seems like the question is just how to convert to ascii then? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30781526/9638646

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, in this case your file name is valid, to catch invalid file names, it is suggested to use [GetInvalidFileNameChars()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

```
 string fileName = "The Animals - House of the Rising Sun ? (1964) + clip compilation ♫♥ 50 YEARS - counting.mp3";

 byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
 char[] characters = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytes);

 string name = new string(characters);
 StringBuilder fileN = new StringBuilder(name);
 foreach (char c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
 {
     fileN.Replace(c, '_');
 }
 string validFileName = fileN.ToString();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 4):

The CD file system is different to the OS file system, so those Path.GetInvalidX functions don't really apply to CDs.

I'm not sure, but possibly the standard you are looking at is ISO 9660
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660
Which has an extremely limited character set in filenames.

I think that Joliet extension to that standard must be in play:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joliet_(file_system)
I think that maybe you are running into the filename length problem more than anything: "The specification only allows filenames to be up to 64 Unicode characters in length".  Your filename is 90 characters long.

Comment: I figured it out I think your original sout code would have worked I just forgot to call it; This is what I ended up with I added this to the end of my code from above  // check for non asccii characters
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            char[] chars = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytes);
            string line = new String(chars);
            line = line.Replace("?", "");
            MessageBox.Show(line);
            return r.Replace(line, replacement);

Comment: One last question how do I use code tags in my comments?

Answer (score 2):

The following code will turn non-ascii characters into '?'

```
string sOut = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s))
```

Then you can use a `sOut.Replace('?', '')` call to take them out. Does this seem like it would work for you?

Comment: I added your code to the beginning of mine and changed out the rest of the input strings to out put the problem is it doesn't allow a empty string litteral and creates an error                                                                                             string sOut = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));
sOut.Replace('?', '');

Comment: I did a Char.parse(" ") it didn't work still get the following error System.ArgumentException: 'Win32 handle that was passed to Icon is not valid or is the wrong type.'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help the final working code is listed below

```
 public static string RemoveIllegalFileNameChars(string input, string replacement = "")
    {
        if (input.Contains("?"))
        {
            input = input.Replace('?', char.Parse(" "));
        }
        if (input.Contains("&"))
        {
            input = input.Replace('&', char.Parse("-"));
        }
        var regexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new     string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
        var r = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(regexSearch)));

        // check for non asccii characters
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        char[] chars = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytes);
        string line = new String(chars);
        line = line.Replace("?", "");
        //MessageBox.Show(line);
        return r.Replace(line, replacement);
    }
```