# Replace special characters with non-special equivalents in a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, character, ascii

I have about 1000 strings (that can change any time (more can be added, some can be removed)) with special characters from various languages. They all contain various special characters such as `ñ`. Is there a way to write a function that would change all special characters in a given string to their normal equivalents (not remove them) so like `ñ` would become `n`. A string `ññoolpę` would turn into `nnoolpe`.

Comment: What do you define as a 'special' character? Is there a definitive list of them? Could you `string.Replace` them, one by one?

Comment: If you do go the `string.Replace` route, use `StringBuilder.Replace` instead. You'll end up producing _**much**_ less garbage

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer elsewhere on SO. If anyone wants to see, here it is:

```cs
string Normalize(string input)
            {
                return string.Concat(input.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Where(
                    c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark));
            }
```

It's from [How to convert from unicode to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460206/how-to-convert-from-unicode-to-ascii).