# c# string to c++ wstring using Encoding.Unicode.Getbytes()

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, encoding, utf-16

So the issue is that when using c# the char is 4 bytes so "abc" is (65 0 66 0 67 0).

When inputing that to a wstring in c++ thru sending it in a socket i get the following output a.

How i am able to convert such a string to a c++ string?

Comment: `i get the following output a.` that's because you tried the bytes as a `std:string`, which is suitable only for single-byte codepages or, due to lack of standardization in C++, UTF8. This interpreted the first null byte as the end of a string. You should use `std::u16string` to read UTF16 bytes.

Comment: BTW you didn't post either your C# or  C++ code, but the bug suggests you're trying to read strings one at a time from C++. For that to work, you need to terminate strings from C#'s side by emitting the appropriate NUL: either a single `0x00` byte for UTF8, or two `0x00` for UTF16.

Comment: *the char is 4 bytes*: no, two bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the issue by using a std::u16string.
Here is some example code

```
std::vector<char> data = { 65, 0, 66, 0, 67, 0 };
std::u16string string(&data[0], data.size() / 2);
// now string should be encoded right
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need ASCII or UTF-8 encoding instead of Unicode.

`65 0 66 0 67 0` is only going to get you the `A`, since the next zero is interpreted as a null termination character in C++.

Strategies for converting Unicode to ASCII can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2460206/102937).

Comment: ASCII or UTF-8 or one of the single-byte encodings. The question does say `wstring` however.

Comment: Either UTF8 encoding, or `u16string` on C++'s side. The 7-bit US-ASCII encoding will mangle any non-English text. UTF8 will emit the same bytes as US-ASCII for English text

Comment: Hello i need this to be loss less and when you convert it to ASCII there is no way to recover the data.

Comment: Sounds like binary data to me, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

> using c# the char is 4 bytes

No, in CSharp Strings are encoded in UTF16. Code units need at least two bytes in UTF16. For simple charachters a single code unit can represent a code point (e.g. 65 0).

On Windows wstring is usually UTF16 (2-4 Bytes) encoded, too. But on Unix/Linux wstring uses usually UTF32-Encoding (always 4 Bytes).

The Unicode code Point has the same numerical value compared to ASCII - therefore UTF-16 encoded ASCII text looks often like this: {num} 0 {num} 0 {num} 0...
See the details here: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)

Could you show us some Code, how you constructed your wstring object?
The null byte is critical here, because it was the end marker for ASCII / ANSI Strings.

Comment: Well i am just passing it the raw data from the socket like so `std::vector<char> data = socket.read();` then `std::wcout << std::wstring(data.begin(), data.end());`
sorry for syntax erorrs (if any) written in this box
also i dont know how to print a u16string but i have tried it in my file pharser and it didnt change any thing

Comment: Well, then I think "socket" stops reading on null byte.

Comment: If you take this code: https://godbolt.org/z/Yds7of. The string constructions seems to work (which is a bit surprising for me).

Comment: No socket is a custom fuction written by me i have looked at the var when in a break point and the data is there it just ends the string at \0

Comment: So the vector has 6 bytes in it...
To handle utf16 you should do something like this:

auto strView =  std::u16string_view(
        reinterpret_cast<char16_t*>(&data[0]),
        data.size()
    );

Comment: this has worked somewhat but there is still a issue i am reading 3 or so too many bytes.
Do you know why this is?

Comment: To help, it would be the best if you could share your code with us....